# Render array's nested object values react

Tags: reactjs

Here is how my `savedLinksData` array prints in my console:

[image]

Here is my code that attempts to get the `linkType` value:

```js
  {savedLinksData.map((saved) => {
        return <h1>{saved.linkType}</h1>;
      })}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I think there may be something wrong with the way I stored the values in the array. It doesn't look like the value are inside of the array.

Picture of `console.log("----->", saved)`

[image]

[image]

```js
const [savedLinksData, setSavedLinksData] = useState([]);

  // query for saved links data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      async function fetchData() {
        const request = await db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user)
          .collection("saved")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setSavedLinks(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
            )
          );
      }
      fetchData();
    } else {
      setSavedLinks([]);
    }
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (savedLinks.length > 0) {
      let newArray = [];
      savedLinks.map((saved) => {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(saved.savedUser)
          .collection("links")
          .doc(saved.savedLinkId)
          .get()
          .then(function (doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              // console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              newArray.push(doc.data());
              // setSavedLinksData([...savedLinksData, doc.data()]);
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log("No such document!");
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
          });
      });
      setSavedLinksData(newArray);
    }
  }, [savedLinks]);
```

Comment: if you console.log(saved) above your return statement what does that show?

Comment: @Ross It prints 6 different objects. Shouldn't they be in an array? Updated with all of my code.

Comment: What does `console.log(snapshot.docs)` say?